# Why viewport meta tag in Chromium is invalid？

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I hope my web to be Mobile browser. I already set `<meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">` in my index.html,and it will display normall in Firefox.(width is device width ,not 980px).But I open the web in Mobile chrome,the layout width is 980px ,not device-width.
Then I add javascript in html:

```
 <script>
(function () {
  function
  autoRootFontSize() {
    document.documentElement.style.fontSize = Math.min(screen.width,
    document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width) / 980 * 320 + 'px';
  }
  window.addEventListener('resize', autoRootFontSize)
  autoRootFontSize();
})();
```

The Mobile Chrome is narmal.Then I have used the commmand 'npm run build'  to package my projects and open the web,but viewport width still is 980px.

How to solve this question ?

Comment: use comma, not semicolon

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag#viewport_basics

Comment: thanks very much ,I should use comma.it's a low level mistake.